# Retrieve ParentID on insert of file

Tags: trigger, contentdocument, files, contentdocumentlink

How to retrieve AccountId on insert of file.

> system.debug('LinkedEntityId $$$$'+LinkedEntityId)

always gives OwnerId.

But after insert of file, I can retrieve two rows from below query on ContentDocumentLink - one row with  AccountId(LinkedEntityId) and one row with OwnerID(LinkedEntityId)

> SELECT LinkedEntityId, Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink
>   where  ContentDocumentId ='069r00000002COX'

```
trigger UpdateAccountWithFileLink on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
        list<Id> accIdList = new list<Id>();
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : trigger.new) {
            system.debug('LinkedEntityId $$$$'+LinkedEntityId);
            if(String.valueOf(cdl.LinkedEntityId).startswith('001')){
              accIdList =  cdl.LinkedEntityId; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if your event is INSERT of a file why don't you create a trigger on ContentDocument instead of ContentDocumentLink?

Comment: @Andrei.Z  ParentID is not available on ContentDocument

Comment: What's the problem here? Are you not getting the accountid is from linkedentityid?

Comment: am not getting accountid from linkedentityid.. But  after insert of file, I can retrieve two rows from below query on ContentDocumentLink - one row with AccountId(LinkedEntityId) and one row with OwnerID(LinkedEntityId)

Comment: SELECT LinkedEntityId, Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId ='069r00000002COX'

Answer (score 0):

@Andrei.Z ParentId is available on ContentDocument if you enable CRM Content and assign to users.

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Peter. For [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm), the ParentId is the ID of the library that owns the document. It's created automatically when inserting a ContentVersion via the API for the first time. I don't think that's the same ParentId that he's looking for. Its best to provide a reference for your answers when posting on SF.SE.

Answer (score 0):

If you're needing the `ContentDocumentLink` record within the trigger context i.e. at the time of the record insertion rather than at any time afterwards, can't you just filter out the record where `LinkedEntityId = :UserInfo.getUserId()`?

`SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,IsDeleted,LinkedEntityId,ShareType,SystemModstamp,Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '0698d000009mNclAAE' AND LinkedEntityId != :UserInfo.getUserId()`